# Maximum number of blocks and the shared memory in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have spent a quite a bit of time reading CUDA documentations, and now I think I am more or less prepared to actually work on CUDA parallelization of my own code.

By the way, what remains to determine the overall parallelization structure is the limit of the usage of the shared memory.

For example, if the shared memory overall is enough, then I probably copy needed information into the shared memory and just play with it. Otherwise, I would try just accessing the global memory for the first parallelization trial and go for the optimization afterwards.

As can be seen in many documents, the space called 'shared memory' seems to have a limit of 48 KB, and the shared memory gets allocated in every block of the threads.

It is obvious that this should not mean that I can have as many blocks of 48KB shared memory as I can. If I use the number of threads per block as 1 (extreme case), then it will overall have x512 times more shared memory compared to the case I use 512 threads per block.

I am with GeForce RTX 3090, and according to this page(https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-rtx-3090.c3622) it seems it has 24GB of memory size. However, this should include the global memory space and so on, right?

Or does it go like this?

1. Allocate M GB needed global memory out of 24GB.
2. If one uses shared memory, one can fully exploit up to (24-M)GB (Although it would be hard to use a few GB of shared memory with 48KB units).

If this is the case I am quite happy to exploit shared memory in my applications.

Comment: Shared memory is part of the L1 cache in hardware for recent GPUs. As automatic caching has become much better in recent generations as well I would start off using global memory, profile and improve. Especially as a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have some misunderstandings on the nature of shared memory and its purpose.

> if the shared memory overall is enough, then I probably copy needed information into the shared memory and just play with it

You didn't describe your algorithm but in general, no. Many simple access patterns can be ordered to work directly on global memory; no need to go through the shared memory. Refer to chapter [9.2.1. Coalesced Access to Global Memory](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#coalesced-access-to-global-memory) in the Best Practices Guide.

If by "play with it" you mean that threads or thread blocks have to do repeated or unordered access to the same block of memory, then yes, fetching that into shared memory is exactly what it is for.

> If one uses shared memory, one can fully exploit up to (24-M)GB (Although it would be hard to use a few GB of shared memory with 48KB units).

The shared memory isn't a "carve-out" of the global memory. It's a separate piece of hardware. A GPU has multiple streaming multiprocessors (SM). Each SM has a separate piece of shared memory on chip. This can be divided among thread blocks that currently run on that SM.

If blocks need a lot of shared memory, it limits the number of blocks that can run on an SM, affecting the overall occupancy (meaning the total number of concurrent threads). Shared memory is one of multiple limiting factors for occupancy. The details are listed in chapter [16.2. Features and Technical Specifications](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications) of the Programming Guide. The number of SMs depends on your specific GPU. Within a GPU generation, models differ mostly in number of SMs and GPU RAM.